# C# compiler is trying to compile to the wrong overloaded method

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, overloading

My project is in VS2012 using .Net 4.5.

I have the following overloaded methods in my class:

```
public SalesOrder GetSalesOrder(int salesOrderID, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    using (iSeriesUOW uow = new iSeriesUOW())
    {
        return GetSalesOrder(uow, salesOrderID, forceRefresh);
    }
}

public SalesOrder GetSalesOrder(iSeriesUOW uow, int salesOrderID, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    .... do some stuff here
}
```

I am trying to call the first method using the following:

```
public void PopulateModel(string companyCode, int salesOrderID, bool forceRefresh)
{
    SalesOrders blSalesOrders = new SalesOrders(companyCode);
    SalesOrder salesOrder = blSalesOrders.GetSalesOrder(salesOrderID, forceRefresh);

    ... Other code here
}
```

The compiler is giving me an error in my GetSalesOrder call:

```
The type 'DataAccess.iSeriesUOW' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Viper.DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

If I remove the forceRefresh in GetSalesOrder, it compiles fine.

I'm thinking that it's trying to call the 2nd GetSalesOrder overload, but I don't know why since the signature of (int, bool) is clearly there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to explicitly set the parameter value:

Instead of

```
 SalesOrder salesOrder = blSalesOrders.GetSalesOrder(salesOrderID, forceRefresh);
```

I'd try

```
public void PopulateModel(string companyCode, int salesOrderID, bool forceRefreshParam)
{
    SalesOrders blSalesOrders = new SalesOrders(companyCode);
    SalesOrder salesOrder = blSalesOrders.GetSalesOrder(salesOrderID, forceRefresh:forceRefreshParam);

    ... Other code here
}
```

Comment: Just to note:  Since the iSeriesUOW class was not available outside of the BusinessLogic class, I modified those calls to internal instead of public.  This also fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm thinking that it's trying to call the 2nd GetSalesOrder overload, but I don't know why since the signature of (int, bool) is clearly there.

Is it really clear?  How do we know that there isn't an implicit conversion from int to iSeriesUOW?

You are expecting rather too much from the C# compiler; we did not spend any time building clever "early outs" into the overload resolution algorithm so that methods that were clearly inapplicable, or applicable but clearly worse, did not have their metadata loaded from disk!

The C# compiler reserves the right to require the *entire transitive closure of assembly references* at compile time, so that it can do a *complete* analysis of the program. There are some limited scenarios in which you can accidentally get away with not providing the entire transitive closure, but *you cannot rely on that*, and *Roslyn will probably require more assemblies to be referenced in some of those scenarios*.

You should get in the habit of providing the transitive closure of assembly references to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the class iSeriesUOW defined? Try adding a reference to the assembly Viper.DataAccess as it says.

Comment: I don't want to add Viper.DataAccess.  It should only be accessible in the BusinessLogic project, not in the MVC app.  The question isn't why can't it find Viper.DataAccess.  It SHOULDN'T be able to find that.  The question is, why is it trying to call the method with 3 signatures instead of 2?

Comment: @Chris, The question is not about adding DAL access. this will not help, just will "replace" wanted method with hidden one.